# Security testing for a AAD authentication web application using OWASP ZAP

Tags: quality-assurance, security-testing, security, zapproxy, ms-azure

I'm having difficulty in how to start security testing for these type of application which has Azure AD authentication. Can someone guide me on how to start this? Do I need to use Zest script for this?

Comment: Did you work out a way to test an AAD application using OWASP in the end? Was it AAD single sign on your authentication?

Comment: Same question? Any luck with that?